# Can't login with appc login

Tags: authentication, appcelerator

I have been using Appcelerator on MacOS for some years and have used 'appc login' from Terminal as a quicker way to login but today it returns an error. Trying to login from Appcelerator also returns an error - 'Bad response from login (incorrect user data), please try again' The suggested troubleshooting page discussed 'Goto Short Links' no longer being available, I don't know what to do from here.

Can anybody help, please?
Brian

Answer (score 1):

There is a replacement for appc:
https://github.com/m1ga/from_zero_to_app/blob/master/appc_to_ti.md

As an alternative, you can modify appc modules to get it running:

I got the appc run command working by changing 3 files. I'm using v9.0.1 and it is installed in
~/.appcelerator/install/9.0.1/

1. ~/.appcelerator/install/9.0.1/package/lib/session.js

in function isSessionExpired add:

```
function isSessionExpired(cfg) {
    return true;
```

2. ~/.appcelerator/install/9.0.1/package/node_modules/appc-platform-sdk/lib/auth.js

in function createSessionFromID add:

```
function createSessionFromID(id, callback) {
    return callback(null, cachedSession);
```

3. ~/.appcelerator/install/9.0.1/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/util.js

in function buildVerify add this before
log(logger.trace, 'sending request %j', data);

```
result = {
    url: urllib.resolve(opts.server, '/api/v1/app/verify'),
    username: json.username,
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    skipped: false
};
callback(null, result);
return;
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have gone over to the Axway CLI and that allows me to login.

Answer (score 0):

This has been happening to me too. On March 1st, Appcelerator was discontinued, which seems to have disabled the use of Appcelerator CLI. To continue development, I recommend switching to the Titanium CLI, as it does not require a login.

In general though, I would recommend changing platform, as there will no longer be any support for new mobile OS versions. I'm making the move over to React Native... slowly..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am going to try an upgrade. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have gone over to the Axway CLI and that allows me to login.