# appcelerator ERROR | Bad response from login (incorrect user data), please try again

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am not able to login into the Appcelerator Studio or using appc cli.
Below is the error message I am getting even after entering the correct credentials.
**ERROR  | Error: Bad response from login (incorrect user data), please try again.**

Unable to install new CLI as well. Below is the command and Error Message.

- appc use
  **ERROR: Download server is not currently available. Please re-try your install again in a few moments. If you continue to have this problem, please contact Appcelerator Support at support@appcelerator.com. [com.appcelerator.install.download.server.unavailable]**

Comment: Please help me with this as I am not able to do any work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe appc CLI login is discontinued as Appcelerator is officially discontinued as of March 2022.

The Titanium CLI will let you continue to work.

You can also take a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71364492), it might help

But overall, it might be a decent idea to look at other platforms as well.  The switch to a different platform was painful and took me about 3 months, but looking back I'm happy I did